# PHP merge images saving transparency

Tags: php, image

I am trying to merge 2 images, both png with the transparent alpha layer. But I got this [image: screenshot]. 
Image with 'A' letter just erase other image and makes it transparent. Here's my code

```
$letterimg = imagecreatefrompng('assets/img/qr/a2.png');
$codeimg = imagecreatefrompng('assets/img/qr/'.$code.'.png');

imagesavealpha($letterimg,true);

imagecopy($codeimg,$letterimg,50,50,0,0,imagesx($codeimg),imagesy($codeimg));

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($codeimg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved by changing image color mode from RGB to indexed color